# $scope.$watch not called whereas model has changed

Tags: angularjs

My $scope.$watch is not triggered when vm.loadStats is called

```
var vm = this;

vm.loadStats = function(){
   vm.propositions = null;
   DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(vm.dateDebut);
   vm.dateFinSever = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(vm.dateDebut);
   vm.propositions = PropositionsAffaireBetweenPropositionDates.get({dateDebut :     vm.dateDebutServer, dateFin : vm.dateFinSever});
}


$scope.$watch(['vm.propositions'], function(newValues, oldValues) {
...
}
```

If anyone knows why...
Thanks

Comment: Why do you put the expression in an array? Is there a particular reason? Angular documentation on $scope.$watch method indicates this parameter should be a string or a function

Answer (score 0):

Angular $scope object has three $watch methods:

- $watch, taking a string or a function
- $watchGroup, taking an array of expressions
- $watchCollection, taking an object

You should either use `$scope.$watch('vm.propositions', ...);` or `$scope.$watchGroup(['vm.propositions'], ...);`

[AngularJS Documentation on $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code... here's a minor fix

```
//Note how I dropped "vm." prefix? its redundant because the strings you provide
//inside the array are translated into $scope.[yourScopedVariable]
$scope.$watch(['propositions'], function(newValues, oldValues) {
...
}
```

Comment: this is strange, this solution doesn't work, it doesn't get called.

Comment: Can't work, $scope is not the same thing as 'vm': vm is a reference to the controller, whereas $scope is... a reference to $scope! Do NOT confuse `$scope` with `this`, they are entirely different things in Angular